# Display GeoJSON on Leaflet web map with GeoDjango

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geodjango

I have to display my geometry data in my Leaflet based web map and I use GeoDjango to display it, I have loaded GeoJSON data and front map but I can't put my geometry data on my web map.

How can we solve it?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import jobs


class hompage(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'

def job_details(request):
    job=serialize('geojson',jobs.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(job,content_type='json')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from .views import hompage,job_details


urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',hompage.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^work/$',job_details,name='works'),
    ]
```

Template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<head>
{%leaflet_js%}
{%leaflet_css%}
    <title>HARISOHMNAATH</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gis{widht:80%;height:700px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js'%}>
</script>
<body>
<h1>harisohmnaath</h2>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function out_layers(map,options){
          var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'works' %}",{
           onEachFeature:function(feature, layer){
                 layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString());
}
});
          datasets.addTo(map);
}
</script>
{%leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste above any errors seen on the developer tools console.  Try replacing `content_type='json'` with `content_type='application/json'`.  What do you get when browsing to `/work`?

Comment: I'm getting my geojson data when i use   http://127.0.0.1:8000/work and getting my leaflet map when http://127.0.0.1:8000 but I cant overlap both  both the data

Comment: Did you fix the content type?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for awhile with your approach until I discovered these two packages: [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) and [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson).

It's maintained and the docs and demos are great.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution. You can load the geojson files using jquery. for this you have to add jquery in your program; i.e.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And replace your code by:

```
$.getJSON("{% url 'work' %}", function(data){
   var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
       layer.bindPopup('pop-up content');
   }
});
geojson.addTo(map);
});
```